# Python extend matrix

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python, and i am storing most of my data is matrixes such as this:

```
users = {
    'user1': {'name':'Jack Renshaw', 'password':'randompass'}
}
```

How can i add a row to this, like with a standard list

Edit:

I actually want to append the data within the matrix, creating a new set. I worded the question poorly. I want to have permanent data stored so i can retrieve it if the application is closed.

Thanks

Comment: you are using a so called `dictionary` to map `users-ids` to a attribute-dictionary. it is unclear what you mean by "add a column" (to what? do you mean 'another attribute'?) and "like a standard list".

Comment: Please don't keep calling a dictionary a matrix, that's confusing.

Comment: okay, i'm new to python. The tutorial called it a matrix

Comment: @JackRenshaw: so, what is your problem now? adding a new attribute to the `dictionary` or to store the data permanently to a storage-medium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a nested [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Note that it doesn't have order, it's just a mapping from keys to values.

You just assign values to new keys:

```
users['user1']['age'] = 21
users['user2'] = {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 30, 'password': 'qwerty'}
```

To save the data to a file you can use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle
with open('data.p', 'wb') as out:
    pickle.dump(users, out)
```

and then to load it

```
with open('data.p', 'rb') as data:
    users = pickle.load(data)
```

Comment: Sorry, i a worded my question poorly. Can you help me with the revised version